# How do I write parameterized queries on an Oracle database using PyODBC?

Tags: python, oracle, odbc

I am trying to use pyodbc to work with an Oracle database.  My database wrapper classes generate parameterized queries, such as this:

```
pyodbcCursor.execute("INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (MY_COLUMN) VALUES (?)", myValue)
```

That function call works when I am connected to a PostgreSQL database, but not when I'm connected to an Oracle database.  The ODBC driver, OraClient10g_home1, is not kind enough to return an error value.  Web pages I've seen seem to indicate that the ideal way to do this is to use the cx_Oracle package, but I don't have that.  Is there some way to get a parameterized query to work without cx_Oracle?  Or should I ask the administrator of this computer to install the cx_Oracle package?

Here is my test code:

```
testCursor = self.MipsDatabase.Cursor()
try:
    testCursor.execute('insert into "RAD_CON_ANNEAL_STATUS" ("SEQUENCE") VALUES (1)')
    self.MipsDatabase.Commit()
except Exception as ex:
    pass

testCursor.execute('select * from "RAD_CON_ANNEAL_STATUS"')
row = testCursor.fetchone()

try:
    testCursor.execute('insert into "RAD_CON_ANNEAL_STATUS" ("SEQUENCE") values (?)', 2)
except Exception as ex:
    pass

try:
    testCursor.execute('insert into "RAD_CON_ANNEAL_STATUS" ("SEQUENCE") values (:0)', (2,))
except Exception as ex:
    pass

try:
    testCursor.execute('insert into "RAD_CON_ANNEAL_STATUS" ("SEQUENCE") values (:1)', (2,))
except Exception as ex:
    pass
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  No change.  I tried using :0 and :1, and using a tuple as you suggested and a list ("[2]").  None of them worked.

Comment: I have added my test code to the question.  It should not matter to pyodbcCursor whether I use a tuple or not, as the docs say it will work with either.  The first insert query apparently works, since the exception complains that I'm trying to violate a unique constraint, which I am.  The select query successfully returns a row.  The remaining queries fail, and the exception message just says "The driver did not return an error code".